# Is visitAnnotation() always called before visitCode() in the ASM library?

Tags: java, testing, junit, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I'd like to instrument only methods annotated with `@Test`, so before `visitCode()` is called, I'd like to know if it's annotated with `@Test` or not. From the tests I ran, I can say that `visitAnnotation()` was always called first, but I don't know if this is always the case, or there are exceptions.

Update: code from ASM:

This is where `visitAnnotation()` is called:

```java
if (runtimeVisibleAnnotationsOffset != 0) {
    attributeLength = this.readUnsignedShort(runtimeVisibleAnnotationsOffset);

    for (currentAnnotationOffset = runtimeVisibleAnnotationsOffset + 2; attributeLength-- > 0;
     currentAnnotationOffset = this.readElementValues(methodVisitor.visitAnnotation(annotationDescriptor, true), currentAnnotationOffset, true, charBuffer)) {
        annotationDescriptor = this.readUTF8(currentAnnotationOffset, charBuffer);
        currentAnnotationOffset += 2;
    }
}
...
...
```

And after this, it calls `visitCode()`:

```java
 if (codeOffset != 0) {
     methodVisitor.visitCode();
     this.readCode(methodVisitor, context, codeOffset);
  }
```

So from this it is pretty clear, that visitAnnotation() is called first, but is this specified somewhere or is it just an implementation detail?

Comment: sorry for the typos, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASM javadoc specifes the order of all method calls and yes, by contract, this order is guaranteed, visitAnnotation is called before visitCode. If you use official ASM emitters such as ClassReader, the order will always follow the specification.

There is however no order guarantee built into the type system. Anybody could implement a different order and some consumers such as ClassWriter tolerate such deviation, even though it's not always explicitly guaranteed.

---

*(Update by kriegaex)* If you want to know for sure, just check out the [ASM manual, chapter 3.2.1](https://asm.ow2.io/asm4-guide.pdf) where this is documented explicitly:

[image: MethodVisitor documentation]

Comment: I took the freedom to add a link to and a screenshot from the ASM manual. Sorry to mess with your 100% correct answer, Rafael, I hope it is okay.

Comment: The lowest part comes from the javadoc.

Comment: It might be more useful to link to [the same Javadoc cited in the PDF](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html): “*The methods of this class must be called in the following order: `( visitParameter )* [ visitAnnotationDefault ] ( visitAnnotation | visitAnnotableParameterCount | visitParameterAnnotation visitTypeAnnotation | visitAttribute )* [ visitCode ( visitFrame | visit<i>X</i>Insn | visitLabel | visitInsnAnnotation | visitTryCatchBlock | visitTryCatchAnnotation | visitLocalVariable | visitLocalVariableAnnotation | visitLineNumber )* visitMaxs ] visitEnd`.*”